# Udacity Introduction to DevOps: Command 'packer build -only=virtualbox-iso application-server.json' not working

Tags: windows, packer

I'm taking the Udacity course to learn more in the field of DevOps (https://github.com/udacity/devops-intro-project), but if I use the following line in the Windows command prompt:

```
packer build -only=virtualbox-iso application-server.json
```

I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\kelvin\Downloads\Documents\DevOps\packer-templates>packer build -only=virtualbox-iso application-server.json
Error: Failed to prepare build: "virtualbox-iso"

1 error occurred:
        * Deprecated configuration key: 'iso_checksum_type'. Please call `packer fix`
against your template to update your template to be compatible with the current
version of Packer. Visit https://www.packer.io/docs/commands/fix/ for more
detail.





==> Wait completed after 0 seconds

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

When trying to fix this with the following line:
packer fix

I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\kelvin\Downloads\Documents\DevOps\packer-templates>packer fix
Usage: packer fix [options] TEMPLATE

  Reads the JSON template and attempts to fix known backwards
  incompatibilities. The fixed template will be outputted to standard out.

  If the template cannot be fixed due to an error, the command will exit
  with a non-zero exit status. Error messages will appear on standard error.

Fixes that are run (in order):

  iso-md5                    Replaces "iso_md5" in builders with "iso_checksum"
  createtime                 Replaces ".CreateTime" in builder configs with "{{timestamp}}"
  virtualbox-gaattach        Updates VirtualBox builders using "guest_additions_attach" to use "guest_additions_mode"
  pp-vagrant-override        Fixes provider-specific overrides for Vagrant post-processor
  virtualbox-rename          Updates "virtualbox" builders to "virtualbox-iso"
  vmware-rename              Updates "vmware" builders to "vmware-iso"
  parallels-headless         Removes unused "headless" from Parallels builders
  parallels-deprecations     Removes deprecated "parallels_tools_host_path" from Parallels builders and changes "guest_os_distribution" to "guest_os_type".
  sshkeypath                 Updates builders using "ssh_key_path" to use "ssh_private_key_file"
  sshdisableagent            Updates builders using "ssh_disable_agent" to use "ssh_disable_agent_forwarding"
  scaleway-access-key        Updates builders using "access_key" to use "organization_id"
  manifest-filename          Updates "manifest" post-processor so any "filename" field is renamed to "output".
  amazon-shutdown_behavior   Changes "shutdown_behaviour" to "shutdown_behavior" in Amazon builders.
  amazon-enhanced-networking Replaces "enhanced_networking" in builders with "ena_support"
  amazon-private-ip          Replaces `"ssh_private_ip": true` in amazon builders with `"ssh_interface": "private_ip"`
  amazon-temp-sec-cidrs      Replaces "temporary_security_group_source_cidr" (string) with "temporary_security_group_source_cidrs" (list of strings)
  docker-email               Removes "login_email" from the Docker builder.
  docker-tag-tags            Updates "docker" post-processor so any "tag" field is renamed to "tags".
  powershell-escapes         Removes PowerShell escapes from user env vars and elevated username and password strings
  vmware-compaction          Adds "skip_compaction = true" to "vmware-iso" builders with incompatible disk_type_id
  hyperv-deprecations        Removes the deprecated "vhd_temp_path" setting from Hyper-V ISO builder templates
  hyperv-vmxc-typo           Fixes a typo replacing "clone_from_vmxc_path" with "clone_from_vmcx_path" in Hyper-V VMCX builder templates
  hyperv-cpu-and-ram         Replaces "cpu" with "cpus" and "ram_size" with "memory"in Hyper-V VMCX builder templates
  clean-image-name           Replaces /clean_(image|ami)_name/ in builder configs with "clean_resource_name"
  spot-price-auto-product    Removes the deprecated "spot_price_auto_product" setting from Amazon builder templates
  qemu-disk-size             Updates "disk_size" from int to string in QEMU builders.
  galaxy-command             Replaces "galaxycommand" in ansible-local provisioner configs with "galaxy_command"
  comm-config                Remove ssh prefixes from communicator port forwarding configuration (host_port_min, host_port_max, skip_nat_mapping)
  ssh-wait-timeout           Replaces "ssh_wait_timeout" with "ssh_timeout"
  vsphere-iso-net-disk       Removes deprecated network and disk fields from "vsphere-iso" builder
  iso-checksum-type-and-url  Puts content of potential "iso_checksum_url" and "iso_checksum_url" in "iso_checksum"
  qemu-host-port             Updates ssh_host_port_min and ssh_host_port_max to host_port_min and host_port_max
  azure-exclude_from_latest  Changes "exlude_from_latest" to "exclude_from_latest" in Azure builders.
  proxmox-type               Updates the builder type proxmox to proxmox-iso

Options:

  -validate=true      If true (default), validates the fixed template.
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Kind regards,
Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
$ packer fix application-server.json
```

Then, it will output a new template that you can copy-paste to the `application-server.json` file.

Afterwards, you can run once again the build command.

Comment: Seen this but doesn't work on my windows 11